# xpath compile using java - NodeList with particular node value

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<data xmlns:fsd="abc.org" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<meta name="elapsed-time" value="46" />
<org-family>
<family-member id="5">
<publication-reference>
<document-id document-id-type="docdb">
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>3056228</doc-number>
<date>20160817</date>
</document-id>
</publication-reference>
</family-member>
<family-member id="2">
<publication-reference>
<document-id document-id-type="docdb">
<country>US</country>
<doc-number>2013315173</doc-number>
<date>20150430</date>
</document-id>
</publication-reference>
</family-member>
</org-family>
</data>
```

From the above xml i want to extract country and date node value, below are my java code

```
NodeList familyMembers = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//family-member//publication-reference//document-id[@document-id-type=\"docdb\"]//text()").evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);

 ArrayList mainFamily = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers.getLength(); i++) {
                    mainFamily.add(familyMembers.item(i).getNodeValue());
                }
```

but its extract all the three node value (`country, doc-number and date`), but i need only the two node value (`country and date`), in the for loop how should i pass the requested node value?

Comment: That is not a valid XML – `<publication-reference>` and `<family-member>` are not closed, and there is no root element.

Comment: Do you know the difference between the `//` and `/` operator in path expressions...? See [XML Path Language (XPath) – 2 Location Paths – 2.5 Abbreviated Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

Comment: @CiaPan : i'm not paste entire xml doc, this is particular section

Comment: Well there's no point posting a subset of your source that isn't well-formed XML. We can't tell where the unclosed start tags are supposed to be closed.

Comment: @MichaelKay : updated my xml in my question

Comment: This doesn't look like a 'particular section'. Instead it looks like several excerpts improperly glued together. In particular, the element `<family-member id="2">` is a descendant (a grand-child, strictly speaking) of `<family-member id="5">` though they apparently should be siblings.

Comment: @CiaPan: agreed your points, again this is for sample xml (i'm edited) my request how to collect only that particular node value

Comment: @Prabu, the XML still isn't well-formed. publication-reference has no end tag.

Comment: @CiaPan Please check the updated xml

Comment: @CiaPan : Hi did you got any idea

Answer (score 0):

<del>Once you selected a `document-id` node, the `//` operator selects its ALL descendants,

then `text()` converts each of them into a string. If you want to process only some of the descentant nodes, just list them (build an explicit sequence of sub-elements).

You can also get rid of expensive (and superfluous here!) `//` operators.

Try replacing the query with

    "//family-member/publication-reference/document-id[@document-id-type=\"docdb\"]/(country, date)/text()"</del>

Comment: Whoops, you're right, that seems XQuery syntax, not a pure XPath!